# Is there a way to use saveXML in R version 3.2.2?

Tags: r

I am trying to use the saveXML code in R, but it is not working.  When I run the saveXML code, I get the following error:

> saveXML(doc, "countryPlain.kml")
>   Loading required package: Rcompression
>   [1] "countryPlain.kml"
>   Warning messages:
>   1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
>     there is no package called ‘Rcompression’
>   2: In saveXML(doc, "countryPlain.kml") :
>     Rcompression is not available, so not attempting to build a KMZ file

When I try to install Rcompression, it does not work because it is not available for R version 3.2.2.  Is there another package/code that does the same thing as saveXML that is available for R version 3.2.2?

Comment: Rcompression doesn't appear to be on CRAN at all.  Try `library("devtools"); install_github("omegahat/Rcompression")` ?